# ReactJS: How to populate specific data from table on two different tabs

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I have created a table that has a first name, last name, number, grade, etc. in the data I have also a line where it either has "graduated": true, "graduated": false, which isn't shown on the actual table but is in the data. I'm trying to display everyone who graduated on one tab and everyone who has not graduated on another tab.

The tabs I have written are:
<tab id="Graduated" value={"1"} label= "Graduated"/>

<tab id="Not Graduated" value={"1"} label= "Not graduated"/>

How would I be able to display the data that has the "graduated": true, when I click on the Graduated tab and the "graduated": false, under the Not Graduated tab?

Everything is in React JS.

Comment: You can use a component to filter the user data into two arrays for graduated true and false, then on click of the tab, the table data binding will be something like `isGraduated ? graduatedTable : notGraduatedTable`. Keep in mind caching this data is crucial for performance, rather than filtering on the fly. For a more detailed answer, I also advice you to provide a https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 1):

I think best answer lies in Javascript array methods, and not in react. You should check [array.filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) and then simply iterate in JSX using it. In example, one tab would be something like:

```
<Tab>
  {fullList.filter(item => item.graduated === true).map(item => {
     ... som edisplay code here
  })}
</Tab>
```

The other list would have `graduated === false` of course.